# Create email with Gmail API

Tags: shell, curl, gmail-api

I'm testing Gmail API here https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.drafts/create but is it possible to create a full email with sender, subject, body and load a gmail template and send it through curl command?

This is what I tried but I am getting an empty message:

[image: https://prnt.sc/1nnxzl7]

Comment: Would like to help but please add in what you have tried so far, to give a complete tutorial of setting up GCP project, configuring credentials, access codes, access tokens, and finally the authorized api request with curl is too much for one question :(

Comment: I don't know what do you need exactly because my question seems to be very simple : is it possible to create a draft email with Gmail api? But not an empty email. Idea is to fill in all the fields (subject, body etc...)

Comment: It's possible yes

Comment: Do you have any demo or documentation using curl command ?

Comment: Have you gotten as far as getting oauth tokens via curl? Or do you have another way to get them and then use them in the curl request?

Comment: Have you had a look at the API documentation? https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.drafts#Draft

Comment: yes I did, but I don't understand where to insert the recipient, the subject, the body etc...

Comment: about oauth tokens this is fine, I know how to generate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235925/discussion-between-iansedano-and-toonetcreation).

Comment: @iansedano : sorry I'm in vacation and not always on my laptop. tell me when you're available ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to send an email based on a draft with the Gmail API

This is one approach you could take:

Using [`users.draft list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.drafts/list?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%7D)

```json
{
  "drafts": [
    {
      "id": "r-1561xxx",
      "message": {
        "id": "179891xxx",
        "threadId": "179891xxx"
      }
    }
  ],
  "resultSizeEstimate": 1
}
```

Then [`users.draft get`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.drafts/get) with one of the `id` in the previous request:

You can retrieve the current MIME message contained in the draft by calling drafts.get with the parameter format=raw.

(The data is sanitized)

```json
{
  "id": "r-1561xxx",
  "message": {
    "id": "179891xxx",
    "threadId": "179891xxx",
    "labelIds": [
      "DRAFT"
    ],
    "snippet": "Name: Reason: Company:",
    "sizeEstimate": 635,
    "raw": "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",
    "historyId": "67xxx",
    "internalDate": "1628xxx"
  }
}
```

The `raw` attribute is where the message is. It's encoded in base64. Decoded it looks like this:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Fri, 13 Aug 2021 16:12:09 +0200
Message-ID: <CAFdukbnrdxQxxxx@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: draft1
From: Sender <sample@gmail.com>
To: Receiver <sample@gmail.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="000000000000eb4b5805c9716fd2"

--000000000000eb4b5805c9716fd2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

Name:

Reason:

Company:

--000000000000eb4b5805c9716fd2
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

<div dir="ltr">Name:<div><br></div><div>Reason:</div><div><br></div><div>Company:</div></div>

--000000000000eb4b5805c9716fd2--
```

#### Sending

In the [guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) it says:

> Create the email content in some convenient way and encode it as a base64url string.
> Create a new message resource and set its raw property to the base64url string you just created.

The text should conform to the [rfc2822](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2822).

So make a plain text email like this (some field you can omit, like date and message ID):

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: draft1
From: Sender <sample@gmail.com>
To: Receiver <sample@gmail.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="000000000000eb4b5805c9716fd2"

--000000000000eb4b5805c9716fd2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

Name: TooNetCreation

Reason: TooNetCreation

Company: TooNetCreation

--000000000000eb4b5805c9716fd2
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

<div dir="ltr">Name: TooNetCreation<div><br></div><div>Reason: TooNetCreation</div><div><br></div><div>Company: TooNetCreation</div></div>

--000000000000eb4b5805c9716fd2--
```

Which encodes to:

```
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
```

Which you can send with:

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"raw":"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"}' \
  --compressed
```

After which it should return an instance of the message and you will have send an email!

#### References

- [`users.draft list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.drafts/list)
- [`users.draft get`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.drafts/get)
- [`users.messages send`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send)
- [Sending email guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending)
  [Working with drafts guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/drafts)

Comment: thanks for the feedback, that's perfect to send the email. but If I want to customize the following fields : FROM, TO, SUBJECT ?

Comment: You just change the text before encoding to b64

Comment: Change `To: whoever <sample@gmail.com>` to whatever you like etc in the plain text email

Comment: ok thank you, I see now. if I need a blank email (with no text inside body), I'm wondering if the fields FROM, TO and SUBJECT could be added directly in curl command without raw value?

Comment: Not with curl, the python client library would be better for that kind of workflow. But in the end it always sends it as an encoded string anyway. See the guide I linked.

Comment: ok many thanks for the feedback, sounds good. have a nice day.